# How do I share a model class between Android and App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

How do I share a model class between Android and App Engine Cloud Endpoints ? I'm using Android Studio.

By share, I mean, have the code written in one place, and used by both projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. Just write your model classes and return such instances from your endpoint methods. Google Cloud Endpoints will generate appropriate classes for Android automatically so you don't have to write them on your own.

Comment: so what if I want to create an instance of that model on the mobile  ? How will that work ?

Comment: You should rather not do this, but you can by using default constructor. If you want to create it on Android but then save it to the backend just provide cloud endpoints method with all the arguments and create it on the backend side.

Answer (score 1):

Just define the model in your backend module. Whilst this will make it possible to reuse the class, it is not a good practice for Android as you might need to make your model implement an interface visible only within your app module, say Parcelable. For that, you will have to decorate the original model.

Answer (score 1):

The **App Engine Java Endpoints Module** template provides a default model to start with. The [Android Endpoints CodeLab](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-codelab-android) has a great step-by-step tutorial on this very subject.

Comment: I have already followed a similar tutorial and implemented endpoints with GCM, but my question is, what if there is a class which I simply wish to have in both projects (and not interact with it through endpoints), would it be better to put it in a library and reference it from both projects ?